# how to make a page number with conditions?

Tags: objective-c

i have 2 IBaction to increase or decrease a page number but
i want my page number is never 0 or under 0

```
-(IBAction)pageNumberPlus1:(id)sender {
labelpageNumberButton.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[labelpageNumberButton.text intValue]+1];}

   -(IBAction)pageNumberMoins1:(id)sender {
   labelpageNumberButton.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[labelpageNumberButton.text intValue]-1];
if (labelpageNumberButton.text <= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",0])  {
    labelpageNumberButton.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",1];}}
```

this code is bad when it decrease it give bad value

Comment: don't do your comparisons with nsstrings but with integers. and save page number as a property instead of storing in a label's text as a string

Comment: have you an example to give?

Comment: i have updated the code, have a look at the edited solution

Answer (score 0):

work's fine with:

```
-(IBAction)pageNumberPlus1:(id)sender { 
self.pageNumber++; 
labelpageNumber.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",_pageNumber]; } 

-(IBAction)pageNumberMoins1:(id)sender { 
self.pageNumber--; 
if(_pageNumber <= 0) _pageNumber = 1; labelpageNumber.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",_pageNumber]; }
```